# push ssl certificate missing private key in keychain

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, push, ssl-certificate, provisioning

I'm updating some apps on the app store in order to integrate Push notification and I have problems with the push ssl certificates.

When I created the apps without push, I used wildcard App ID like `myradio.*` and then I created new explicit App ID corresponding to the bundle ID of the app like `myradio.radioname`.

I had configured push with certificates, but not used it on the moment, and now that I need to use these App IDs, when I install the Development and Production Push SSL Certificates, they are missing private key in the Keychain.
Maybe it's because I revoked my Development certificate. But for some apps all works fine.

It is impossible to create another App ID with the same suffix, and it is impossible to use the existing, so have you any idea on how to update my apps ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to just change the bundle identifier inside your application, then create a new App ID and provisioning profiles withe the new identifier? Like for example your apps current bundle ID is com.myradio.radioname why not just change it to com.radio.radioname. I hope I understood what you were asking. I personally just use [Parse.com's push notifications](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) which is extremely easy to set up, I suggest you look into it.